# Is there any way to auto lock device if person using app decides to just exit out without answering question

Tags: android, ios

Ex: app for children that automatically asks a educational question every 5 min(kind of like an alarm type thing) If instead of answering question kid decides to exit out of the app is there anyway to auto lock and require password before using device again?

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, are you working on Android or iOS?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to programmatically lock the device is through having your app be a Device Admin and using device administration functionality.  Device administration is a large topic, but you can see the documentation at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin